# Why do I need to cast a struct returned from a function?

Tags: c

In one file I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static struct node* mynode;

struct node*
example(void)
{
    mynode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ...fill up the struct here...
    return mynode;
}
```

The calling routine is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
    mynode=example();
}
```

The node itself is defined in a defs.h file I don't show here.
The warning I get when compiled with gcc is "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" in the calling routine.

Changing to mynode=(struct node*)example(); removes that warning. The routine works in any case but I don't understand why I'm getting the warning.

Comment: @JamesMorris - Yes, I included the defs file but forgot my header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file calling `example`, the return type of `example` is not known, so it is assumed to return an int, which you assign to `struct node *`. Hence the warning.

You should either declare the prototype for `example` in the calling file (typing in `struct node* example(void);` before the calling function) or (better) create a header file called, say, example.h, where you type in the prototype and then include the header file in the calling file (that is, typing in `#include "example.h" at the top). The header file thus defines the interface of the file where`example` is located, and the files using the functions can include the header file, thus making sure all the types match, and removing any compiler warnings.

Comment: Argh! And that's the issue. I had a header file but didn't include it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be you didn't declare a prototype for `struct node* example(void)` and the compiler thinks it returns an `int` ?